# Plasma Ion Temperature Measurement with Baffled Langmuir Probe

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, plasma-physics

Recently, a new article proposed the use of a Baffled Langmuir probe for Ion temperature Measurements. The model is based on the classical Langmuir model

$$
            I_{e}(V_{b})
            =
            \left\{
                \begin{array}{cc}
                    I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}\exp{\left(\frac{-e\left(V_{s}-V_{b}\right)}{k_{B}T_{e}}\right)} &,\quad V_{b}\leq V_{s} \\
                    I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}} &,\quad V_{b}>V_{s} \\
                \end{array}
            \right.
            $$
$$
        I_{i}(V_{b})
        =
        \left\{
            \begin{array}{cc}
                -I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}\exp{\left(\frac{e\left(V_{s}-V_{b}\right)}{k_{B}T_{i}}\right)} &,\quad V_{b}\geq V_{s} \\
                -I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}} &,\quad V_{b}<V_{s} \\
            \end{array}
        \right.
        $$
In Langmuir Probe theory, the expresion for $I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}$ is known also:
$$I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}=en_{e}A\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T_{e}}{2\pi m}}$$
And also, the expresion for the floating potential:
$$I_{e}(V_{f})+I_{i}(V_{f})=0$$
$$
V_{s}-V_{f}
=
        \left\{
            \begin{array}{cc}
                 \frac{k_{B}T_{e}}{e}\ln{\left(\frac{I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}}{I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}}\right)}&,\quad V_{f}<V_{s} \\
                \frac{k_{B}T_{i}}{e}\ln{\left(\frac{I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}}{I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}}\right)}&,\quad V_{f}>V_{s} \\
            \end{array}
        \right.
$$
Where $V_{s}$, $T_{e}$, $I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}$ and $I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}$ are determined experimentally

So, the $T_{i}$ measurement is said to come from a simple substraction. Given that you can control $I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}/I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}$. Taking that $V_{f}^{\textrm{opt}}\approx V_{s}$ occurs when $I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}/I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}\sim1$ and that $V_{f}^{\textrm{max}}$ occurs when $I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}/I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}}\ll1$.

The author says: "Thus, subtracting $V_{f}$ of an optimally shielded baffled probe ($V_{f}^{\textrm{opt}}$) from $V_{f}$ of a maximally shielded baffled probe ($V_{f}^{\textrm{max}}$) yields $T_i$, as well as its fluctuation amplitude, frequency, and phase." Which would mean that $V_{f}^{\textrm{max}}-V_{f}^{\textrm{opt}}=\frac{k_{B}T_{i}}{e}$. But I wouldn't be sure how that exactly is achived, I tried to do a expansion of $\ln{(I_{e}^{\textrm{sat}}/I_{i}^{\textrm{sat}})}$, but wasn't sure if that was the right approach, if anyone can give any inputs it would be great, the article is https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0043602.

Comment: I think you have $V_{f}$ and $V_{s}$ backwards in your last expression.

Comment: That's right, gonna edit it